# Dealing with repeating code in asp.net mvc 3 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a controller that deals with forms/documents and the more I advance with the tasks the more repeating parts of code I see in my methods. It's my first `ASP` application at all mvc or not and I'm not sure what is the best way to optimize my code. Something that I've noticed - a pattern that is repeated several time is this :

```
public ActionResult DisplayForm(int? documentId, long status)
        {
            ViewBag.Status = status;

            List<MCS_DocumentFields> model = (List<MCS_DocumentFields>)DocumentFieldService.GetFieldsForDocument(documentId);

            var finalModel = model
                .OrderBy(c => c.ContentTypeId)
                .ThenBy(c => c.RowNo)
                .ThenBy(c => c.ColumnNo)
                .ThenBy(c => c.MCS_Fields.Order)
                .ToList();
            return View(finalModel);
        }
```

This is a method that displays a certain form. But when the form is edited I deal with this in another method :

```
 public ActionResult UpdateDocument(List<MCS_DocumentFields> collection)
        {
            //TODO deal with the repeating code
            int? documentId = (int)collection[0].MCS_Documents.Id;
            ViewBag.Status = 1;
            List<MCS_DocumentFields> model = (List<MCS_DocumentFields>)DocumentFieldService.GetFieldsForDocument(documentId);

            var finalModel = model
                .OrderBy(c => c.ContentTypeId)
                .ThenBy(c => c.RowNo)
                .ThenBy(c => c.ColumnNo)
                .ThenBy(c => c.MCS_Fields.Order)
                .ToList();

            //var ts = collection;
            return View("DisplayForm", finalModel);

        }
```

I have to implement the logic for data validation and updating, but at the end I want to show the same view - the edited form with the new data and some proper message like "Save successfull"  or something like this.

So I wonder what can I do here - write some private methods in my controller which I'll call where needed. Maybe there's a way to... as in the example - deal with the saving in `UpdateDocument` method, but then `UpdateDocument` to return `DisplayForm` method.. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return with a call to your DisplayForm method, something like this:

```
public ActionResult UpdateDocument(List<MCS_DocumentFields> collection)
{
    //TODO deal with the repeating code
    int? documentId = (int)collection[0].MCS_Documents.Id;
    long status = 1;
    List<MCS_DocumentFields> model = (List<MCS_DocumentFields>)DocumentFieldService.GetFieldsForDocument(documentId);

    return DisplayForm(documentId, status);
 }
```

And in DisplayForm, you should specify the name of the view to render, changing

```
return View(finalModel);
```

with

```
return View("DisplayForm", finalModel);
```

**Addendum**

You should take a look at the Post-Redirect-Get or PRG pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

When following that pattern, you could instead in the end of the UpdateDocument method, return a redirect to DisplayForm.

```
return RedirectToAction("DisplayForm", new{ documentId, status });
```

Comment: Thnaks, it doesn't seem like many people want to tell something on this topic so I'll accept your answer and gonna try your suggestions to optimize my code.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your application I suggest doing the sorting within the DocumentFieldService.GetFieldsForDocument method if you can.

If you cannot do that you could do something like this:

```
public List<MCS_DocumentFields> GetSortedFieldsForDocument(documentID)
        {

            List<MCS_DocumentFields> model = (List<MCS_DocumentFields>)DocumentFieldService.GetFieldsForDocument(documentId);

            var sorted = model
                .OrderBy(c => c.ContentTypeId)
                .ThenBy(c => c.RowNo)
                .ThenBy(c => c.ColumnNo)
                .ThenBy(c => c.MCS_Fields.Order)
                .ToList();

            return sorted;
        }
```

As a private method like you say then you can do:

```
public ActionResult DisplayForm(int? documentId, long status)
        {
            ViewBag.Status = status;
            return View(GetSortedFieldsForDocument(documentId));
        }
```

and

```
public ActionResult UpdateDocument(List<MCS_DocumentFields> collection)
        {
            //TODO deal with the repeating code
            int? documentId = (int)collection[0].MCS_Documents.Id;
            ViewBag.Status = 1;

            return View("DisplayForm", GetSortedFieldsForDocument(documentId));

        }
```

In your controller.